# Value of hashing/encrypting passwords in the greater scheme of things

Tags: security, hash

If someone is able to get passwords out of my app's database, surely they could just get the data out instead, seeing as at the end of the day no hacker is really interested in a password alone I would imagine, therefore what is the real value of obscuring users passwords?
Would keeping security data and app data in different databases strengthen security, by assuming that if they are able to get into one database, they cannot necessarily get into the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleartext value of the password can be used to attack the user's account elsewhere. This is especially relevant if the value of *your* data to the potential attacker is perceived as low.

This is a rather common attack scenario, in fact. Instead of brute-forcing someone's account at Google, you brute-force their account at mydinkyforum.com, where there's no CAPTCHA and no account lockout due to its inherently dinky nature. Then try the retrieved password at Google. You'd be surprised.

Comment: That is a very good point. Users often have the same username/password combo with multiple sites.